# Unit Test APIs with OAuth2 Implicit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a set of APIs that take JWT tokens and I have unit test coverage for each of those APIs. It is easy for me to pass a JWT token and test those.
My JWT token is based on a user consent.
So far I take the JWT token, place it somewhere in the unit test and then execute them.

Before I start my unit test, is there a way for me to popup a dialog and get the user consent thus getting the JWT token and then continue my unit tests?

This will allow me to

- Not hard code a JWT token
- Easily change between different users with different roles

Comment: Please share some code of your unittest's. There should be no need to enter a JWT token at all. If you want to test what your code does with certain roles you should fake the JWT.

Comment: I don't *recommend* this solution, but if you are set on having the user type the JWT in, it would work.

You could create a System.Windows.Form object, do a form.ShowDialog(), during the test allowing the user to enter the data.
When the dialog closes, the test would automatically continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up using Selenium which ended up being advantageous.
Example code below.

```
WebBrowser = new ChromeDriver();
IWebElement inputEMail, inputPassword, loginButton;

WebBrowser.Navigate().GoToUrl(
    "http://www.yourOAuthProvider.com?client_id=ABCDE&AnyAdditionalParameters");

Thread.Sleep(1 * 3000);

this.Log(this.WebBrowser.Title);

inputEMail = this.WebBrowser.FindElement(By.Name("email"));
inputEMail.SendKeys("user@example.com");

inputPassword = this.WebBrowser.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
inputPassword.SendKeys("PasswordAtExampleDotCom");

loginButton = this.WebBrowser.FindElement(By.ClassName("submit"));
loginButton.Click();

Thread.Sleep(1 * 3000);

this.Log(this.WebBrowser.Url);

WebBrowser.Close();
```